# Upload csv files to database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

HI Guys I have A problem I want to upload csv files and store to database
But doesn't work..
I tried to debug it several times but not working hope you help me guys.
 I Have a csv file containing..

`firstname lastname middlename gender`

`test       test     test       male`

Then when I upload this csv file doesn't work.

This is my code..

```
<?php 

    session_start();
        include ("config.php");



            $extension = end(explode(".",basename($_FILES['file']['name'])));

            if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] < 10485760 && $extension== 'csv')
            {
                $file   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $handle = fopen($file, "r");

                try 
                {
                    $connection = new pdo("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=upload",$username,$password);


                    if

                    $upload = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_upload(firstname,lastname,middlename,gender)
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

                    if($handle !== false)               
                    {

                        fgets($handle);
                        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ',') !== false))
                        {

                            $upload->execute($data);

                        }

                        fclose($handle);

                        $connection = null;

                        echo "<p class='bg-success'>Upload Success</p>";
                        header ("location: index.php");
                    }   

            }
            catch(pdoExecption $e)
            {   
                die($e->getmessage());
            }
        }

        else
        {
            header("location:config.php");
        }

?>
```

thanks for the help..

Comment: Could you explain what exactly doesnt work and where is the problem?

Comment: 'Doesn't work' - succinct, accurate and totally useless. Explain what should happen and what is actually happening. FWIW you have at least one typo here: `catch(pdoExecption $e)`

Comment: What error messages are you receiving?

Comment: I got no error
redirect me to index.php

Comment: Hi @MikeW When I Upload a csv file nothing hapen no error but redirect me to index.php which means success...

Comment: Comment out the header line like this //header ("location: index.php");
Make sure errors are turned on at the top of the script:
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Now do you get any errors?

Comment: It doesn't mean success. It means it looped through your file but $upload->execute($data);probably isn't actually doing anything.

Comment: Hi guys I have a error
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\upload.php on line 30

Comment: So that means that your $data variable is not an array of data so it cannot be uploaded. Try adding printf($data); inside your while loop. That will show you what $data contains on ever iteration

Comment: HI I Got number 1 and the error
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in

Comment: Well this part isn't working then: while($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ',') !== false) - what happens if you change it to: while($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ','))

Comment: thank you my problem is now solved
hahah

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not viable.

To import CSV you can either use the mysqlimport utility or you have to split the csv records in separate fields to match your INSERT statement. You cannot just feed CSV to the insert statement and hope that it sorts out things for itself.

Comment: Hi can u Give me sample I have no idea
because still newbie
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a little CsvImport class I wrote some time ago make importing CSV a little bit easier

```
<?php
    final class CsvImport {
        private $file = "";
        private $fields = array(); //array("field1", "field2", "field3"); ...
        private $data = array(); //array([1] => array("value", "value", "value") ...
        private $delimiter = "";
        private $fieldCount = 0;
        private $rowCount = 0;
        private $internalCounter = 0;
        private $loaded = false;

        public function __construct($_file, $_delimiter = "") {
            $this->file = $_file;
            if(is_file($this->file) == true) {
                if(($handle = fopen($this->file, "r")) !== false) {
                    //If the delimiter is not set try to suggest it
                    if(strlen($_delimiter) == 0) {
                        $this->delimiter = $this->suggestDelimiter();
                    } else {
                        $this->delimiter = $_delimiter;
                    }
                    if(strlen($this->delimiter) > 0) {
                        $row = 0;
                        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $this->delimiter)) !== false) {
                            if($row == 0) {
                                $this->fieldCount = count($data);
                            }
                            if($this->fieldCount > 0) {
                                for($c = 0; $c < $this->fieldCount; $c++) {
                                    if($row == 0) {
                                        $this->fieldCount = count($data);
                                        $this->fields[] = $data[$c];
                                    } else {
                                        $this->data[$row][$this->fields[$c]] = utf8_encode($data[$c]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            $row++;
                        }
                        $this->rowCount = $row;
                        if($this->fieldCount > 0) {
                            $this->loaded = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public function getNextRow() {
            $retVal = false;

            if($this->loaded == true) {
                if($this->internalCounter < $this->rowCount) {
                    $this->internalCounter++;
                    $retVal = true;
                } else {
                    $this->internalCounter = 0;
                }
            }

            return $retVal;
        }

        public function readField($field) {
            $retVal = false;
            if($this->isLoaded() == true) {
                if(isset($this->data[$this->internalCounter][$field]) == true) {
                    $retVal = $this->data[$this->internalCounter][$field];
                }
            }

            return $retVal;
        }

        public function resetInternalCounter() {
            $this->internalCounter = 0;
        }

        public function getFieldCount() {
            return $this->fieldCount;
        }

        public function getRowCount() {
            return $this->rowCount;
        }

        public function getFieldList() {
            return $this->fields;
        }

        public function getDelimiter() {
            return $this->delimiter;
        }

        public function isLoaded() {
            return $this->loaded;
        }

        private function suggestDelimiter() {
            $retVal = "";

            $file = fopen($this->file, 'r');
            $content = fgets($file);
            fclose($file);

            if(strlen($content) > 0) {
                $list = array(
                    "," => substr_count($content, ","),
                    "." => substr_count($content, "."),
                    "&" => substr_count($content, "&"),
                    "%" => substr_count($content, "%"),
                    "-" => substr_count($content, "-"),
                    ";" => substr_count($content, ";"),
                    "'" => substr_count($content, "'"),
                    "\"" => substr_count($content, "\""),
                );

                $maxCount = 0;

                foreach($list as $key => $value) {
                    if($value > 0) {
                        if($value > $maxCount) {
                            $retVal = $key;
                            $maxCount = $value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return $retVal;
        }

        private function __clone() { }
    }
?>
```

The usage is as simple as this:

```
$file = "/path/to/file.csv";
$import = new CsvImport($file);
if($import->isLoaded() == true) {
    while($import->getNextRow()) {
        foreach($import->getFieldList() as $fieldName) {
            $value = $import->readField($fieldName);
            echo $fieldName . " => " . $value . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure you can build your queries with all  field names in the foreach loop and fire each query in the while loop.